# prettyPhoto remove the expanding image option

Tags: jquery

does anyone know how to remove this silly expand image option (http://screencast.com/t/Xclao9m84) on the prettyPhoto? This makes no sense why someone would want this and it's ruining my logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add this to the page (or modify it for JS include).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(
    {
        allow_resize: false, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */
    });
});
```

via [chibilicious](http://chibilicious.com/prettyphoto-easy-fixes)

Answer (score 3):

With the Wordpress theme I used which had the plugin there was a **"js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"** file that contained the following settings:

```
opacity: 0.80, /* Value between 0 and 1 */
show_title: true, /* true/false */
allow_resize: true, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */
allow_expand: false, /* Allow the user to expand a resized image. true/false */
default_width: 500,
default_height: 344,
```

I just set the `allow_expand` option to false and that removed the expand image option.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your prettyphoto.js and change this code:

```
if(pp_dimensions['resized']){$('a.pp_expand,a.pp_contract').show();}
```

with:

```
if(pp_dimensions['resized']){$('a.pp_expand,a.pp_contract').hide();}
```

default is 'show' > change it in 'hide'